# Expand VMDK that is not in a snapshotted VM

Tags: vmware-workstation

So I had this VM that decided that it preferred the bitbucket after a BSOD due to a power outage (this is my personal workstation).

Thankfully, I had a clone to work from so not all was lost, but now I'm trying to expand its drive and its claiming that I cannot do so because the VM has snapshots.  The old VM did, yes, but the clone (independent) doesn't have any snapshots.  Going to snapshot manager proves that.

How can I deal with this so that I can expand my new (cloned) VM disk?

This is using VMWare Workstation 9

Thanks

Comment: I would try to take another snapshot and then, to delete all snapshots. This should possibly commit all even not directly visible snapshots in snapshot manager.

Comment: I'd also see what "vmrun listSnapshots" has to say.  But the above suggestion seems like it might work.

Comment: This is a full clone and not a linked one, yes?

Comment: @quadruplebucky yes, this is a full clone

Comment: @dsmsk80 tried that, did not work

Comment: what does "vmrun -T ws listSnapshots <path-to-your.vmx>" tell you?

Comment: PS D:\Work\Projects\CPS\TempClone> vmrun -T ws listSnapshots .\CPS.Clone.vmx
Total snapshots: 2
AutoProtect Snapshot
AutoProtect Snapshot

Comment: Deleting the Autoprotect snapshots, I was able to expand.  Thank you. Repost as an answer so I can mark it as answered and you can bask in all the glory that gives :)  First time I've used vmrun, any good resources you know of?